# Pegar registros criados em um range de datas MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Caros amigos,

Eu tenho uma tabela mysql que recebe os dados do efetivo da mão de obra em um cliente de minha empresa.

Cada registro do DB possui uma data de inicio (Quando esse serviço começou a ser prestado nesse cliente) e uma data de final (Quando esse serviço deixou de ser prestado.

Eu preciso pegar os efetivos ativos no cliente entre uma data **x** e uma **y**.

Até ai, meu SQL resolve.

```
"SELECT * FROM `EFETIVO_POSTO` WHERE `COD` = '$chave' AND `INICIO` >= '$dataIni' AND `FINAL` <= '$dataFin'"
```

O problema é que caso essa consulta seja realizada com a data de hoje, ele precisa mostrar o efetivo que existe naquele cliente hoje, independente da data em que esse serviço começou a ser prestado.

Idéias são bem vindas não só em MySQL como também em PHP e até em JS (Visto que isso mais tarde vai gerar um JSON pra ser utilizado pelo JS)

Comment: Você quer os efetivos que estão sendo executados hoje? Ou seja, que começaram hoje ou em alguma data anterior e que ainda estão sendo executados?

Comment: @Pedro Teles Isso ai, de datas anteriores que ainda estão em execução.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM EFETIVO_POSTO WHERE COD = $chave AND INICIO <= CURDATE() AND FINAL IS NULL --retorna os efetivos que AINDA estão sendo executados
```

Imagino que se ainda não foi concluído, a data final deve ser null. Por isso a instrução `IS NULL`

Combinando com o código que você já havia postado temos:

```
SELECT * FROM EFETIVO_POSTO WHERE COD = '$chave' AND ((INICIO >= '$dataIni' AND FINAL <= '$dataFin') OR (INICIO <= CURDATE() AND FINAL IS NULL))
```

Comment: Isso deve resolver pra pegar os que estão funcionando atualmente. Ai eu faço duas situações diferentes, uma pegando os que estiveram ativos em uma determinada faixa de tempo e essa pra pegar os de hoje?

Comment: Se você precisar das duas situações separadamente sim. Mas se precisar listar ao mesmo tempo terá que combinar dos dois selects

Comment: O ideal seria listar ao mesmo tempo. E essa combinação dos dois selects seria feita como? Juntando os arrays resultantes com o php?

Comment: Dá uma olhada na edição que fiz e veja se te atende.

Comment: Perfeito! Valeu Pedro.